# Do concussions affect children more profoundly than adults?

Tags: lasting-effects-duration, head-trauma, middle-aged-adults, children-kids, concussion

Concussions are a serious matter no matter what age you are. Of course innumerable factors are at play, but in general, **do concussions affect children more profoundly than they do adults?** In other words, if the same type(degree?)of concussion occurred to a child and adult, will it have more lasting damage to the child? (for argument's sake... they are in the same overall health....) **Why or why not?**